# gunicorn worker failed to boot

Tags: python, heroku, atom-editor, gunicorn

I am trying to open an app with Heroku. The following is the error log.

```
PS C:\PythonPrograms\mysite\demo> heroku logs --tail

2018-11-25T19:02:21.195848+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 129, in init_process

2018-11-25T19:02:21.195850+00:00 app[web.1]: self.load_wsgi()

2018-11-25T19:02:21.195852+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 138, in load_wsgi

2018-11-25T19:02:21.195856+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()

2018-11-25T19:02:21.195858+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi

2018-11-25T19:02:21.195860+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()

2018-11-25T19:02:21.195862+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load

2018-11-25T19:02:21.195864+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()



2018-11-25T19:02:21.195865+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 41, in load_wsgiapp

2018-11-25T19:02:21.195868+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)

2018-11-25T19:02:21.195870+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 362, in import_app

2018-11-25T19:02:21.195871+00:00 app[web.1]: app = eval(obj, vars(mod))

2018-11-25T19:02:21.195873+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<string>", line 0

2018-11-25T19:02:21.195874+00:00 app[web.1]:

2018-11-25T19:02:21.195876+00:00 app[web.1]: ^

2018-11-25T19:02:21.195917+00:00 app[web.1]: SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

2018-11-25T19:02:21.196233+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-11-25 19:02:21 +0000] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)

2018-11-25T19:02:21.297175+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-11-25 19:02:21 +0000] [11] [ERROR] Exception in worker process

2018-11-25T19:02:21.297179+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):

2018-11-25T19:02:21.297181+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker

2018-11-25T19:02:21.297183+00:00 app[web.1]: worker.init_process()

2018-11-25T19:02:21.297185+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 129, in init_process

2018-11-25T19:02:21.297187+00:00 app[web.1]: self.load_wsgi()

2018-11-25T19:02:21.297189+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 138, in load_wsgi

2018-11-25T19:02:21.297190+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()

2018-11-25T19:02:21.297192+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi

2018-11-25T19:02:21.297194+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()

2018-11-25T19:02:21.297196+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load

2018-11-25T19:02:21.297198+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()

2018-11-25T19:02:21.297200+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 41, in load_wsgiapp

2018-11-25T19:02:21.297202+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)

2018-11-25T19:02:21.297203+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 362, in import_app

2018-11-25T19:02:21.297205+00:00 app[web.1]: app = eval(obj, vars(mod))

2018-11-25T19:02:21.297206+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<string>", line 0

2018-11-25T19:02:21.297208+00:00 app[web.1]:

2018-11-25T19:02:21.297210+00:00 app[web.1]: ^

2018-11-25T19:02:21.297211+00:00 app[web.1]: SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

2018-11-25T19:02:21.297361+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-11-25 19:02:21 +0000] [11] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 11)

2018-11-25T19:02:21.340381+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):

2018-11-25T19:02:21.340381+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):

2018-11-25T19:02:21.340411+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 210, in run

2018-11-25T19:02:21.340917+00:00 app[web.1]: self.sleep()

2018-11-25T19:02:21.340934+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 360, in sleep

2018-11-25T19:02:21.341372+00:00 app[web.1]: ready = select.select([self.PIPE[0]], [], [], 1.0)



2018-11-25T19:02:21.341379+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 245, in handle_chld

2018-11-25T19:02:21.341632+00:00 app[web.1]: self.reap_workers()

2018-11-25T19:02:21.341637+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 525, in reap_workers

2018-11-25T19:02:21.341971+00:00 app[web.1]: raise HaltServer(reason, self.WORKER_BOOT_ERROR)

2018-11-25T19:02:21.342042+00:00 app[web.1]: gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3>

2018-11-25T19:02:21.342049+00:00 app[web.1]:

2018-11-25T19:02:21.342051+00:00 app[web.1]: During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

2018-11-25T19:02:21.342052+00:00 app[web.1]:

2018-11-25T19:02:21.342054+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):

2018-11-25T19:02:21.342056+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/bin/gunicorn", line 11, in <module>

2018-11-25T19:02:21.342179+00:00 app[web.1]: sys.exit(run())

2018-11-25T19:02:21.342184+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 61, in run

2018-11-25T19:02:21.342338+00:00 app[web.1]: WSGIApplication("%(prog)s [OPTIONS] [APP_MODULE]").run()

2018-11-25T19:02:21.342341+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 223, in run

2018-11-25T19:02:21.342566+00:00 app[web.1]: super(Application, self).run()

2018-11-25T19:02:21.342568+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 72, in run

2018-11-25T19:02:21.342714+00:00 app[web.1]: Arbiter(self).run()

2018-11-25T19:02:21.342720+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 232, in run

2018-11-25T19:02:21.342933+00:00 app[web.1]: self.halt(reason=inst.reason, exit_status=inst.exit_status)

2018-11-25T19:02:21.342939+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 345, in halt

2018-11-25T19:02:21.343205+00:00 app[web.1]: self.stop()

2018-11-25T19:02:21.343208+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 393, in stop

2018-11-25T19:02:21.343506+00:00 app[web.1]: time.sleep(0.1)

2018-11-25T19:02:21.343509+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 245, in handle_chld

2018-11-25T19:02:21.343712+00:00 app[web.1]: self.reap_workers()

2018-11-25T19:02:21.343717+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 525, in reap_workers

2018-11-25T19:02:21.344061+00:00 app[web.1]: raise HaltServer(reason, self.WORKER_BOOT_ERROR)

2018-11-25T19:02:21.344095+00:00 app[web.1]: gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3>

2018-11-25T19:02:21.454244+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1

2018-11-25T19:02:31.103999+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn script1: app`

2018-11-25T19:02:30.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded

2018-11-25T19:02:34.064741+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-11-25 19:02:34 +0000] [11] [ERROR] Exception in worker process

2018-11-25T19:02:34.064761+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):

2018-11-25T19:02:34.064761+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):

2018-11-25T19:02:34.064763+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker

2018-11-25T19:02:34.064765+00:00 app[web.1]: worker.init_process()

2018-11-25T19:02:34.064767+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 129, in init_process

2018-11-25T19:02:34.064769+00:00 app[web.1]: self.load_wsgi()

2018-11-25T19:02:34.064771+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 138, in load_wsgi

2018-11-25T19:02:34.064772+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()

2018-11-25T19:02:34.064774+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi



2018-11-25T19:02:34.064775+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()

2018-11-25T19:02:34.064780+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load

2018-11-25T19:02:34.064782+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()

2018-11-25T19:02:34.064783+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 41, in load_wsgiapp

2018-11-25T19:02:34.064785+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)

2018-11-25T19:02:34.064786+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 362, in import_app

2018-11-25T19:02:34.064788+00:00 app[web.1]: app = eval(obj, vars(mod))

2018-11-25T19:02:34.064789+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<string>", line 0

2018-11-25T19:02:34.064791+00:00 app[web.1]:

2018-11-25T19:02:34.064792+00:00 app[web.1]: ^

2018-11-25T19:02:34.064794+00:00 app[web.1]: SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

2018-11-25T19:02:34.064795+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-11-25 19:02:34 +0000] [11] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 11)

2018-11-25T19:02:34.220738+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-11-25 19:02:34 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master

2018-11-25T19:02:34.220743+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-11-25 19:02:34 +0000] [4] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.

2018-11-25T19:02:34.354918+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed

2018-11-25T19:02:57.984656+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=katyjosapp.herokuapp.com request_id=fefbfee6-b4ed-40a6-b745-492565340b51 fwd="24.56.217.129" dyno

= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

2018-11-25T19:02:58.684235+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=katyjosapp.herokuapp.com request_id=5e3a604e-316b-4cec-b19d-eae46b915384 fwd="24.56.21

7.129" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

2018-11-25T19:28:33.780279+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting

2018-11-25T19:28:45.697251+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn script1: app`

2018-11-25T19:28:48.579126+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-11-25 19:28:48 +0000] [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.9.0

2018-11-25T19:28:48.579996+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-11-25 19:28:48 +0000] [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8846 (4)

2018-11-25T19:28:48.580150+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-11-25 19:28:48 +0000] [4] [INFO] Using worker: sync

2018-11-25T19:28:48.595528+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-11-25 19:28:48 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10

2018-11-25T19:28:48.641751+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-11-25 19:28:48 +0000] [11] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 11

2018-11-25T19:28:49.113220+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-11-25 19:28:49 +0000] [11] [ERROR] Exception in worker process

2018-11-25T19:28:49.113258+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):

2018-11-25T19:28:49.113261+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker

2018-11-25T19:28:49.113263+00:00 app[web.1]: worker.init_process()

2018-11-25T19:28:49.113264+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 129, in init_process

2018-11-25T19:28:49.113266+00:00 app[web.1]: self.load_wsgi()

2018-11-25T19:28:49.113268+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 138, in load_wsgi

2018-11-25T19:28:49.113269+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()

2018-11-25T19:28:49.113271+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi

2018-11-25T19:28:49.113273+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()

2018-11-25T19:28:49.113274+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load

2018-11-25T19:28:49.113276+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()

2018-11-25T19:28:49.113277+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 41, in load_wsgiapp

2018-11-25T19:28:49.113279+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)

2018-11-25T19:28:49.113281+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 362, in import_app

2018-11-25T19:28:49.113282+00:00 app[web.1]: app = eval(obj, vars(mod))

2018-11-25T19:28:49.113284+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<string>", line 0

2018-11-25T19:28:49.113286+00:00 app[web.1]:

2018-11-25T19:28:49.113288+00:00 app[web.1]: ^



2018-11-25T19:28:49.113289+00:00 app[web.1]: SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

2018-11-25T19:28:49.113291+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-11-25 19:28:49 +0000] [11] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 11)

2018-11-25T19:28:49.461812+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-11-25 19:28:49 +0000] [10] [ERROR] Exception in worker process

2018-11-25T19:28:49.461829+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):

2018-11-25T19:28:49.461832+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker

2018-11-25T19:28:49.461834+00:00 app[web.1]: worker.init_process()

2018-11-25T19:28:49.461835+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 129, in init_process

2018-11-25T19:28:49.461837+00:00 app[web.1]: self.load_wsgi()

2018-11-25T19:28:49.461839+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 138, in load_wsgi

2018-11-25T19:28:49.461841+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()

2018-11-25T19:28:49.461843+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi

2018-11-25T19:28:49.461844+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()

2018-11-25T19:28:49.461846+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load

2018-11-25T19:28:49.461848+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()

2018-11-25T19:28:49.461849+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 41, in load_wsgiapp

2018-11-25T19:28:49.461851+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)

2018-11-25T19:28:49.461853+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 362, in import_app

2018-11-25T19:28:49.461854+00:00 app[web.1]: app = eval(obj, vars(mod))

2018-11-25T19:28:49.461856+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<string>", line 0

2018-11-25T19:28:49.461858+00:00 app[web.1]:

2018-11-25T19:28:49.461860+00:00 app[web.1]: ^

2018-11-25T19:28:49.461931+00:00 app[web.1]: SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

2018-11-25T19:28:49.462982+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-11-25 19:28:49 +0000] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)

2018-11-25T19:28:49.609662+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):

2018-11-25T19:28:49.609671+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 210, in run

2018-11-25T19:28:49.613569+00:00 app[web.1]: self.sleep()

2018-11-25T19:28:49.613610+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 360, in sleep

2018-11-25T19:28:49.613995+00:00 app[web.1]: ready = select.select([self.PIPE[0]], [], [], 1.0)

2018-11-25T19:28:49.614031+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 245, in handle_chld

2018-11-25T19:28:49.614321+00:00 app[web.1]: self.reap_workers()

2018-11-25T19:28:49.614354+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 525, in reap_workers

2018-11-25T19:28:49.614769+00:00 app[web.1]: raise HaltServer(reason, self.WORKER_BOOT_ERROR)

2018-11-25T19:28:49.614937+00:00 app[web.1]: gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3>

2018-11-25T19:28:49.614962+00:00 app[web.1]:

2018-11-25T19:28:49.614965+00:00 app[web.1]: Duaceback (most recent call last):

ring handling of the above exception, another ele "/app/.heroku/python/bin/gunicorn", line 11, in <module>

xception occurred:                             s.exit(run())

2018-11-25T19:28:49.614966+00:00 app[web.1]:   le "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 61, in run

2018-11-25T19:28:49.614994+00:00 app[web.1]: TrGIApplication("%(prog)s [OPTIONS] [APP_MODULE]").run()

aceback (most recent call last):               le "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 223, in run

2018-11-25T19:28:49.615023+00:00 app[web.1]: Fiper(Application, self).run()

le "/app/.heroku/python/bin/gunicorn", line 11,le "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 72, in run

in <module>                                   biter(self).run()



2018-11-25T19:28:49.619467+00:00 app[web.1]: syle "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 232, in run

s.exit(run())                                  lf.halt(reason=inst.reason, exit_status=inst.exit_status)

2018-11-25T19:28:49.619525+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 345, in halt

le "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packlf.stop()

ages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 61, in run le "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 393, in stop

2018-11-25T19:28:49.619921+00:00 app[web.1]: WSme.sleep(0.1)

GIApplication("%(prog)s [OPTIONS] [APP_MODULE]"le "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 245, in handle_chld

).run()                                        lf.reap_workers()

2018-11-25T19:28:49.619953+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 525, in reap_workers

le "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packise HaltServer(reason, self.WORKER_BOOT_ERROR)

ages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 223, in run   nicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3>

2018-11-25T19:28:49.620314+00:00 app[web.1]: su Process exited with status 1

per(Application, self).run()                    State changed from starting to crashed

2018-11-25T19:28:49.620344+00:00 app[web.1]: Fi

le "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-pack

ages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 72, in run

2018-11-25T19:28:49.620641+00:00 app[web.1]: Ar

biter(self).run()

2018-11-25T19:28:49.620672+00:00 app[web.1]: Fi

le "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-pack

ages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 232, in run

2018-11-25T19:28:49.621035+00:00 app[web.1]: se

lf.halt(reason=inst.reason, exit_status=inst.ex

it_status)

2018-11-25T19:28:49.621079+00:00 app[web.1]: Fi

le "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-pack

ages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 345, in halt

2018-11-25T19:28:49.621521+00:00 app[web.1]: self.stop()

2018-11-25T19:28:49.621551+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 393, in st

op

2018-11-25T19:28:49.622034+00:00 app[web.1]: time.sleep(0.1)

2018-11-25T19:28:49.622065+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 245, in ha

ndle_chld

2018-11-25T19:28:49.623053+00:00 app[web.1]: self.reap_workers()

2018-11-25T19:28:49.623083+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 525, in re

ap_workers

2018-11-25T19:28:49.625273+00:00 app[web.1]: raise HaltServer(reason, self.WORKER_BOOT_ERROR)

2018-11-25T19:28:49.625645+00:00 app[web.1]: gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3>

2018-11-25T19:28:49.780852+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1

2018-11-25T19:28:49.802154+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed

!    Logs eventsource failed with: 401 Unauthorized
```

How can I fix this?

Edit: Ok, here is my main script file. Like I said in the comments, there are more files where the issue might be.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template("home.html")

@app.route('/about/')
def about():
    return render_template("about.html")
if __name__=="__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Windows 10, using Atom editor, Python 3.7.0

Comment: We can't help much without seeing your code. Please add a [mcve].

Comment: Hey I'm a bit new to this, and there are a few files involved. Here is the script of the app file. Please let me know if you need to see all the files.                                                              from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template("home.html")

@app.route('/about/')
def about():
    return render_template("about.html")
if __name__=="__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)

Comment: It's okay, we were all new at this sometime. It's basically impossible to read code in comments (especially Python, where whitespace is semantically important). Please [edit] your question and add the code there. After pasting, select it and press Ctrl+K or click the `{}` button to format it as code.

Comment: Hi @Chris I edited the post with the code from the main script file.